# Angular 16 - issues with routing to child routes

Tags: angular

Angular 16 routing...
I have child routes that are protected - these all work as expected.
I also have child routes that are unprotected and all but one work correctly.
The route "resetpassword" is always redirecting me to the login page and never routing to the resetpassword page.

Here is my route array:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: SecureLayoutComponent, canMatch: [canMatchAuthenticated],
    children: [
      { path: '', component: PageDashboardComponent },
      { path: 'users', component: PageUsersComponent },
      { path: 'user', component: PageUserComponent },
      { path: 'companies', component: PageCompaniesComponent },
      { path: 'company', component: PageCompanyComponent },
      { path: 'professionals', component: PageProfessionalsComponent },
      { path: 'professional', component: PageProfessionalComponent },
      { path: 'member', component: PageProfessionalComponent },
      { path: 'landingreports', component: PageLandingReportsComponent },
      { path: 'landingreport', component: PageLandingReportComponent },
      { path: 'cohorts', component: PageCohortsComponent },
      { path: 'cohort', component: PageCohortComponent }
    ],
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
  },
  {
    path: '', component: LoggedOutLayoutComponent, canActivate: [canActivateUnauthenticated],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'login', component: PageLoginComponent },
      { path: 'forgotpassword', component: PageForgotPasswordComponent },
      { path: 'resetpassword', component: PageResetPasswordComponent },
    ],
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
  }
];
```

The Authenticated Guard

```
const canMatchAuthenticated: CanMatchFn = (route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]) => {
  let b = inject(AuthService).isAuthenticated();
  return b;
}
```

The Unauthenticated guard

```
const canActivateUnauthenticated: CanActivateFn = (route: Route, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
  let b = !(inject(AuthService).isAuthenticated());
  return b;
}
```

Given a link such as: `mydomain.com/resetpassword?token=<some-token>`
The application always ends up at the login screen.
When I use the Alt+Back - it will go to the resetpassword screen.
I have tried everything I can to get it to work and have looked for a couple of days for a solution.
Can anyone help?

**Edit**
Got rid of deprecated `CanActivate` derived classes.
Switched to `canMatch` for the `SecureLayoutComponent`.
Still does not work.
Please help!

Comment: Can you show the code of the guard too?

Comment: Your `SecureLayoutComponent` and `LoggedOutLayoutComponent` use the same `path: ''` which is not right. Please use different route path.

Comment: @Phix - I added the guards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your goal is to skip the `SecureLayoutComponent` on route `''` when `AuthenticatedGuard` returns `false`, and then proceed to show `LoggedOutLayoutComponent` on route `''` if `UnauthenticatedGuard` returns `true`.

In that case, you should use the `canMatch` route guard on `SecureLayoutComponent` instead of `canActivate`. `canMatch` is the only guard that will skip the current route if the guard returns `false` and will proceed with other `Route` configurations. In contrast, `canActivate` will cancel the navigation if *any* guard returns `false`.

You can read more about it in the Angular documentation for [canMatch](https://angular.io/api/router/CanMatchFn) and [canActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateFn).

Comment: Thank you @Karel.  However, the 'login' route is in the unauthenticated routes.  I did try your suggestion and it does not get me past the issue.

Comment: I try make an example with same routing and it works. Are you sure you don't have any logic navigate to login page?, only thing you can do it now is debugging. Find line code navigate with login path

Comment: @HuấnNguyễnXuân, I do not.

Comment: Could you reproduce it on stackblitz? @Jim

Comment: @HuấnNguyễnXuân, Actually, yes.   Hidden deep down it was redirecting.  thank you.